# Data Validation List with formula in the options of the list

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have had a search around for this and cant find anything or maybe I can't find the right terms to search for.

My problem: Currently my drop down options (in cell drop down) are listed as follows

```
"PASSED,FAILED,NOT APPLICABLE,NOT TESTED,See Section X,—"
```

When "See Section X" is selected I would like a formula to populate X with the cell immediately to the right

In VBA you would write something like below but a validation list does not take this.

```
"PASSED,FAILED,NOT APPLICABLE,NOT TESTED,See Section " & cells(current_row,current_col +1).value & ",—"
```

In the column to the right I would put a second dropdown with "A,B,C" and then the "See Section X" option would read "See Section "

Any ideas or links that might help me come up with an appropriate solution?

Comment: Change it at the List source. You can have a formula at the list source based on the second drop down. So when the second dropdown changes. The values of the list will change. Thus changing the values of the dropdown 1

Comment: @SivaprasathV I believe this will change the "See Section X" to the A/B/C globally but I need each row (that this drop down is in) to be potentially a different A/B/C option.

Comment: @SivaprasathV like so ? https://snag.gy/kbmu7t.jpg

Comment: None should be typed. There are 2 dropdowns one for "A,B,C" the other with "PASSED,FAILED,NOT APPLICABLE,NOT TESTED,See Section X,-". when "See Section X" is selected I want the "X" to populate with the "A,B,C" from the other drop down so each row would read "See Section A" "See Section B" etc etc. Every row could be a different "A,B,C" option.

Answer (score -1):

Create a list and define your data validation to use that list (I'm only talking about the 2nd list). In the last cell in this list you would reference the cell where your first selection is located. Something like:

```
="See Section "&$a$1
```

Assuming the first data validation is happening in in $a$1.

Each time the first drop down is used, the values for the 2nd will be updated. No code necessary, just a simple concatenation formula at the bottom of your list.

Comment: I think I must be missing something. The "See Section X" does not change per row but once, its almost as if I need the formula to be the selectable item in the drop down. Col K has section number list options. Col M has results options. The table starting A4 is what the table is doing right now, Col F is what the result column should be. I have attached a screen shot https://snag.gy/zuNSR6.jpg

Comment: Now that I understand your problem, my suggestion isn't going to work. I think what you need to do is use a Form Control Combo Box instead of Data Validation. Use a list for values and define a target cell (any cell can be selected instead of the active cell in Data Validation). Point to your target cell at the end of list 2 to create your custom value array. One issue I see right now is if you select A in row 4, then select your 2nd drop down in row 5, it will give you the selection you chose for row 4. This can all be resolved with some macro logic that kicks off when you make a selection.